# Linear Algebra without Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

How far could one get in linear algebra without matrices?  It seems like the more I learn, the less I actually use them, but most of the basic theorems and invariants that learned first -- and still use -- were defined via matrices.  Could linear algebra be done without matrices at all?  Is there a book that takes this approach?  I'm just curious how one would go about it.

Comment: You could just replace every matrix with the corresponding linear transformation.

Comment: One of the big reasons I think they use matrices also is because though you could prove theorems with matrices with its corresponding linear map, the matrices also allow for ease for talking about certain concepts. Such as I know theorems in my book define matrix concepts to prove theorems like and upper triangular matrix and such that would be very messy and long winded to explain through vectors and linear maps

Comment: Matrices are useful as a symbolical and computational tool. They encode information in a very useful manner. One could discard them, but, as Bane says, "it would be extremely painful."

Comment: Matrices allow you to make calculations mechanical, and to state results concisely. There are definite instances where matrices save you times and ink.

Comment: If I recall correctly, *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Axler does this approach.

Comment: I'm not claiming that matrices aren't useful -- the thing about them though is that they are inherently coordinate-dependent.

Comment: @user160678 I would say that matrices are very useful when talking concepts in finite vector spaces but if you want to make concepts about general vector spaces including infinite ones than concept of matrix applied to this wouldn't be very useful and many of theorems that come from matrices that we have don't apply to those type of vector spaces. But if there are still some important concepts that only apply to finite vector spaces that are still useful so matrices can be use to aid when delving into those

Comment: @Clarinetist thats the book I actually used for my class and even though and it will still prove theorems using matrix concept you just don't see actual matrices written out very much in book. But yes it does largely go with approach of not using matrices

Comment: One can read more about the Axler book at http://linear.axler.net --- Axler says the book is intended for a *second* course in linear algebra.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That label is unwarranted, I think. The book requires no prior knowledge of linear algebra (and I indeed used it as my first text when I self-taught the subject).

Comment: \\Started reading his website\\ Why does Axler seem to dislike determinants so much?  Maybe I had a better professor than most, but I didn't have any problem with them.  Maybe the formulas seemed pretty unmotivated *at first* but then we defined them as the amount by which an oriented object changes (generalized) volume under a linear transformation and it all made sense.

Comment: @user160678 Probably because they're clunky. The definition of a determinantal mapping is cumbersome and unmotivated, at least for me.

Comment: @Ayesha I like the definition that a determinant is the signed (generalized) volume of the parallelotope with sides as the vectors.  It makes sense of me.  Of course when I have to compute one, though, I just use Mathematica.

Comment: That seems to be what's really at the heart of the formula $\underline T(i) = (\det \underline T) i$ that Muphrid gives below, too.

Comment: You should check out the book [Linear Algebra via Exterior Products](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/Kayed/eBooksLectureNotes/Linear_Algebra_via_Exterior_Products_By_Sergei_Winitzki.pdf) by Sergei Winitzki.  I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You absolutely do not need matrices to talk about linear operators.

At its barest, a matrix represents a linear function of a vector.  Given an input vector $a$, a linear function $\underline T$ might be written like this:

$$\underline T(a) = (a \cdot u) \ell + (a \cdot v) m + (a \cdot w) n + \ldots$$

This is a very "dumb" way of translating a matrix to a more basis-independent notion.  The vectors $u, v, w, \ldots$ would be colums, and the vectors $\ell, m, n$ would simply be chosen basis vectors, $e_1, e_2, e_3, \ldots$.  They *need not be* basis vectors in a particular basis, however.

Now, in itself, this kind of translation from matrices to basis-independent language isn't terribly useful.  All you've done is take the columns of the matrix and put that information into the vectors $u, v, w, \ldots$.  A *very general* matrix may have no other simpler way of writing the linear function, but many *interesting* matrices, corresponding to *interesting* transformations, often do.

Using clifford algebra, you can simplify the explicit expression for a rotation matrix in terms of a rotor--the clifford algebra analogue of a quaternion.  A rotation map $\underline R$ looks like

$$\underline R(a) = q a q^{-1}$$

And so, instead of explicitly working with the rotation matrix, much information is invested in the rotor $q$ instead.  The explicit form of this map lends itself to easy generalization to *objects beyond vectors*, also.  Orthogonal projections can also be condensed considerably from the most general form.

So, one reason you might not want to work with a matrix is when you can write the linear function with much more compact and powerful expressions instead.

---

Many of the properties of matrices are properties of their associated linear operators and do not require matrices to compute them.

For example, trace:  you're often taught to sum over diagonal elements to compute trace.  But consider instead the usual derivative operator $\nabla$.  What happens when you do this?

$$\nabla \cdot \underline T(a) = \text{scalar}$$

The result is a scalar.  It's *the trace*.  So, instead of a computation that requires you to write the matrix of a transformation, you can compute the divergence of a linear function and get its trace that way.  If you can compute this divergence without choosing a basis at all, it's a net win.

Similarly, there is a natural extension of any linear operator to *blades*:  simple products of several vectors under the wedge product.  Blades are natural representations of subspaces--that don't require matrices!--and give considerable geometric insight to linear algebra.  Indeed, any exterior algebra built on a base vector space $\mathbb K^n$ has a single linearly independent $n$-blade.  Call this $n$-blade $i$, and the natural extension of the linear operator acting on this $n$-blade is

$$\underline T(i) = (\det \underline T) i$$

This can be a basis independent way of defining the determinant; no matrix required!  And yes, the $n$-blade $i$ carries the same meaning as a volume object in the space; this is a direct translation of the common geometric idea of looking at a volume's dilation or shrinking under a transformation.

---

I mentioned blades from exterior algebra.  Linear algebra with matrices often relies excessively upon characterizing subspaces through, for instance, the kernel of a linear transformation.  Using blades to represent subspaces instead frees you from having to represent subspaces through projection maps' kernels.  For instance, it's often that one represents a 2-blade through an antisymmetric matrix.  You no longer need a matrix to do this if you use the exterior algebra instead.

---

No longer having to use matrices, certain aspects of linear algebra have to be thought of differently:

Similarity transformations take on an obvious meaning, as they are just changes of basis.  Linear functions written in basis-independent language have little need of such things.  Thus, the difference between a diagonal operator and one that is merely *diagonalizable* is just one of a choice of basis, for instance.

Things like QR factorization are also basis dependent, and so they focus more on the practical matter of doing computations rather than expressing a linear function in terms of something intrinsic to its properties.

---

When you no longer use matrices to encode, for instance, the inner product, the notion of symmetry of a linear map becomes a bit clearer:  that we need to use the conjugate transpose for complex maps is something that can initially seem mysterious, but it follows directly from the definition of the complex inner product and the notion that $\underline T(a) \cdot b = \overline T(b) \cdot a$, which defines the relationship between a linear map and its adjoint.  You begin to realize that matrices are *inextricably designed* for Euclidean space, and over the years, various hacks and other simple tricks have been designed to keep them useful for other applications.  All of these things, like the conjugate transpose, have the feel of dirty tricks needed just to keep all the math making sense, where in a basis-independent formulation, these cracks and seams in matrix algebra are no longer of any consequence.

---

Make no mistake: going away from matrices may mean you need other math to make computations make sense.  I've made references to clifford algebra and exterior algebra here, for instance.  Did you know you can *invert a linear operator* without using matrix inverse formulas?  This is very possible to do with clifford algebra, but you do need the formalism to get all the requisite operations in place to actually do the computation.  And of course, the result will ultimately be the same.

For numerical applications, you'll be tied to using some basis all the time anyway.  I can't foresee a future in which matrices are not used in computing for sheer speed and convenience, but one should always understand that the principal results of linear algebra do not require matrices to be proven, and it can be instructive to prove them without matrices.  And often, basis-independent formulations of linear maps can be convenient to use for certain applications.

---

I've based most of this answer on my knowledge of clifford algebra--specifically the newer "geometric algebra" that is used in some physics circles and that tries to cut down on some complex notations to make things look more like vector algebra and vector calculus.  Some authors in the subject include Hestenes and Sobczyk; Doran and Lasenby; Dorst, Fontijne, and Mann; and Alan Macdonald, who in particular has written texts appropriate even for undergraduates that relate traditional methods of linear algebra to a more geometric algebra perspective.

Comment: How do you show that the divergence of a linear transformation is the trace?  I've never heard that before.

Comment: Is an n-blade the same as an n-form?  Or are they related?

Comment: Re: divergence.  You could break the input vector into components with respect to a basis, and the partial derivatives from the divergence would eventually get you the trace.  A basis-independent way of doing the problem would be to consider each term of the form $(a \cdot u) \ell$, where $a$ is the input vector.  $\nabla \cdot [\ell(a \cdot u)] = \ell \cdot u$, by turning the divergence into a directional derivative.  When $\ell$ is a basis vector, you realize that you just start extracting the diagonal components of the corresponding matrix (remember $u$ corresponds to a column).

Comment: Re: blades and forms.  A *blade* could be an $n$-vector or an $n$-form.  Remember $n$-vectors are formed from wedge products of tangent vectors while $n$-forms are formed from wedge products of cotangent vectors ("covectors", "dual vectors", or 1-forms).  The word *blade* signifies that the product is *simple*: formed *just* from a product of $n$ (co)vectors, and not a sum of products that have no common factors.  For instance, $e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4$ is a 2-vector, but it is not *simple*; you cannot factor it, so it is not a blade.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with linear maps, matrices are a great help to simplify your task. Instead of taking the image of a vector by your map, you multiply the matrix associated to this map by the vector (written as a column matrix). So why should this tool be excluded?

Comment: As I said, I'm not claiming that matrices aren't useful - they clearly are.  But matrices are coordinate-dependent, only represent functions btw finite-dimensional vectors spaces, and *to me* make it somewhat opaque that what I'm actually doing when using matrices is finding properties of linear transformations.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake.